# Textarea outof Box when reject any Edit suggession

Tags: discussion, support, bug, status-completed, design

While reviewing Suggested Edits, if I reject an edit suggestion, the TextArea of the "Causes Harm" option goes outside of the pop-up. See the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I have pushed a fix for this. The change will be on live site after the next production build.